# Get the uploaded file from AWS S3 after it has been uploaded

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Consider the code :

```js
    var express = require('express'),
        aws = require('aws-sdk'),
        bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
        multer = require('multer'),
        multerS3 = require('multer-s3');

    aws.config.update({
        secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        region: 'us-east-1'
    });

    var app = express(),
        s3 = new aws.S3();

    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    var upload = multer({
        storage: multerS3({
            s3: s3,
            bucket: 'bucket-name',
            key: function (req, file, cb) {
                console.log(file);
                cb(null, file.originalname); //use Date.now() for unique file keys
            }
        })
    });

    //open in browser to see upload form
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');//index.html is inside node-cheat
    });

    //use by upload form
    app.post('/upload', upload.array('upl',1), function (req, res, next) {
        res.send("Uploaded!");
    });

    app.listen(3000, function () {
        console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
    });
```

How can I get the file that the user uploaded in node **after** it has been successfully uploaded to the bucket ?

I need to do some manipulations to the file after it has been uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you successfully uploaded the file, it will return you an url. With the url you can retrieve the file which has been uploaded. Then you can use nodejs function fs.readFileSync(file path) to read the file.

Comment: What returns a URL ?

Comment: after u called upload, print the respond, you will get it in the respond.